# Excel looping problem1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called "Comp.xlsx" and in the same workbook a sheet named "List". The data in the list sheet looks some thing

```
SheetName   Column1   Column2    Column3     Column4
-----------------------------------------------------
Sheet1      a              b        c            d
Sheet2      a              b        c            d
Sheet3      a              b        c            d
Sheet4      a              b        c            d
Sheet5      a              b        c            d
```

In a folder i have 10 workbook, what i need to loop through these workbook, if the Sheetname on the "List" matches the sheet name in the workbooks during looping, I need the program to copy column1 to column4 and paste in the sheet at some calculated address. I have been trying to do this but unable to do

My code looks something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim rpt As Workbook
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim bcnt As Integer
Dim wbn As String
Dim wsn As String
Dim wsexist As Boolean
Dim createnwb As Boolean
Dim SFile As String
Dim Spath As String


Set twb = ThisWorkbook '
Set tws = twb.Sheets("List")

Spath = "C:\Users\m\Desktop\V\" ' or where your source files stored
SFile = Dir(Spath & "*.xlsx")
Do While Len(SFile) > 0
Set rpt = Workbooks.Open(Spath & SFile) 'or where the file sits

twb.Activate
tws.Activate

Range("a1:a100").Select
bcnt = Selection.Count



For i = 4 To bcnt
    wbn = Cells(i, 1).Value
    ''wsn = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 31)
    wsexist = False
    createnwb = False
    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 3).Value Then
        'createnwb = True
        Range("b" & i, "e" & i).Copy
    End If

    rpt.Activate
    For Each sh In Worksheets
    Application.Sheets(sh.Name).Select
        If sh.Name = wbn Then
        Application.Sheets(sh.Name).Select
            Range("a1").Select

        Cells.Find(What:="Inter-company", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 1).Select

        ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

       '' ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Offset(5, 4).Select

            End If
            'rpt.Activate
            ''On Error Resume Next

            wsexist = True

         Next sh
            Exit For

    ''Next sh


Next i
''SFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: Where does the code fail?

Comment: till copying it is fine, but it is not able to paste the values in the proper sheets. It is working only for first sheet.

Comment: Team can any one of you help on this..i am still struggling

Answer (score 0):

i have done it..

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim lRow&, i&, sPath$, sFile$, iSh As Worksheet, shRng As Range, fndCell As Range
    Dim tmpWB As Workbook

    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set shRng = .Range("A4", "A" & lRow)
    End With

    sPath = "C:\Users\m\Desktop\V\" ' or where your source files stored
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile, False, False)

        For Each iSh In tmpWB.Sheets
            Set fndCell = shRng.Find(iSh.Name, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
                fndCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 4).Copy

                iSh.Cells.Find(What:="Inter-company", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                    False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(5, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=True
            End If
        Next

        tmpWB.Close True

        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```